# How is a rocket mounted w.r.t. gimbal?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rocket-science

[Gimbal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal) is used to balance the rocket from tripping after its launch.  But, how is a rocket mounted with respect to the gimbal system?

Answer (score 1):

The rocket nozzle is mounted on a bearing that can tilt a small amount in two directions - allowing it to steer the direction of the exhaust and so the direction of thrust. [Thrust vector nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_vectoring)

The gimbal linked in the article is for the sensor platform used to measure the direction, although now you would use a solid state 3d acceleration sensor instead of a gimbal.

Just to add to the confusion, it is possible to steer a satelite or spacecraft once the engines have stopped by using a gimbal called a reaction wheel.  A spinning wheel stays pointing in the same direction so it is possible to tilt an object floating in space by grabbing onto the axle of a heavy spinning wheel and using it as a "fixed" object to steer yourself around